# python regex:Consider end of line as an OR condition in a search, similar to characters in character class

Tags: regex, python-3.x, findall, end-of-line

Problem:
Find all vowels (more than 2) that are sandwiched between two consonants. These vowels can come at beginning or end of line.
Example:-

input :-

```
abaabaabaabaae
```

expected output :-

```
['aa','aa','aa','aae']
```

solution Tried

```
import re
pattern=re.compile(r'(?:[^aeiouAEIOU])([AEIOUaeiou]{2,})(?=[^AEIOUaeiou])')
pattern.findall("abaabaabaabaae")
```

This gives output as  ['aa','aa','aa'] , it ignores 'aae' for obvious reason as end of line is not part of search criteria. How can I include an anchor - end of line ($) inclusive search such that it($) is an OR condition in the search and not an mandatory end of line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract matches of the regular expression

```
re'(?<=[b-df-hj-np-tv-z])[aeiou]{2,}(?=[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]|$)'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eGG4Uo/2/)

For the following string the matches are indicated.

```
_abaab_aabaabaaeraaa_babaa%abaa
   ^^     ^^ ^^^             ^^
```

I found it easiest to explicitly match consonants with the character class

```
[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]
```

[Python demo](http://tpcg.io/HoJoHI8r)

Comment: Your regex pattern in line 2 has a dangling unclosed double quote.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `re.findall` with the pattern `(?<=[^\Waeiou])[aeiou]+(?![aeiou])`:

```
inp = "abaabaabaabaae"
matches = re.findall(r'(?<=[^\Waeiou])[aeiou]+(?![aeiou])', inp, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aae']
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
(?<=[^\Waeiou])  assert that what precedes is any word character, excluding a vowel
                 this also exlcudes the start of the input
[aeiou]+         match one or more vowel characters
(?![aeiou])      assert that what follows is not a vowel (includes end of string)
```

Comment: `[^\Waeiou]` is problematic because it matches digits and undescores.

Comment: Then the OP can use `[^\Waeiou0-9_]` ... my guess is that for the OP's input, only consonants would be appearing.

Comment: No harm, no foul to use what you just suggested.